# Hibernate model scanPackages()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have multiple hibernate model classes in different packages.

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
    builder
        .scanPackages("com.chaitanya.users.model")
        .scanPackages("com.chaitanya.department.model")
        .addProperties(getHibernateProperties());

    return builder.buildSessionFactory();
}
```

Is this right way to define model in different packages or should i define all model in one package so that no need to write multiple `scanPackage()`.

There will be muliple model in the application so do we need to write scanPackages for all model?

Comment: The method is called `scanPackages` you can put as many packages in there as you like. How you structure your code is highly opiniated but packaging by functionality rather then technical layer is goog thing imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scanPackages method accepts one or more Java package names. So just chain them like this:

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
builder
        .scanPackages("com.chaitanya.users.model", "com.chaitanya.department.model")
        .addProperties(getHibernateProperties());

     return builder.buildSessionFactory();
}
```